Swift5 Hashable(Equatable)に準拠したプロトコル型のインスタンスが配列のcontainsを利用できない
プロトコルについての学習のため次のようなプログラムを作成しました．
しかしながら下記の

if !list.contains(v){

の行で

Cannot convert value of type 'any Vector' to expected argument type '(any Vector) throws -> Bool'

というエラーが表示されてしまいます．
VectorList構造体のプロパティであるlistを[IntVector]とし，イニシャライザの引数であるany Vector.TypeをIntVectorとすることでこのエラーを回避できるのですが，汎用化のため具体的な型ではなくプロトコルを指定したいと考えています．
プロトコルを指定したままでcontains(_:)メソッドを利用できる方法はないでしょうか．
Swift version: 5.8.1
protocol Vector:Hashable{
    static func == (lhs: any Vector, rhs: any Vector) -> Bool
    var x:Int { get set }
    var y:Int { get set }
}

extension Vector{
    init(x:Int,y:Int){
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
    static func == (lhs: any Vector, rhs: any Vector) -> Bool {
        if lhs.x != rhs.x{ return false }
        if lhs.y != rhs.y{ return false }
        return true
    }
}

struct VectorList{
    var list:[any Vector]
    init(n:Int,VType: any Vector.Type){
        while list.count < n{
            let x = Int.random(in: 0...5)
            let y = Int.random(in: 0...5)
            let v = VType.init(x:x,y:y)
            if !list.contains(v){  // ここでコンパイルエラー
                list.append(v)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct IntVector:Vector{
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
}

var vl = VectorList(n: 10, VType: IntVector) // このように利用したい

